# Display partial view results in modal dialog box

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a textbox on my form:

```
 <input type="text" class="input-group-field" id="draftSearchProducts" name="draftSearchProducts" placeholder="SearchProducts" />
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchResults(string keywords, int queryLimit = 20, int offset = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            ProductSearchResults searchResults = new ProductSearchResults();

            ComApiData<GetProductsDataConnector> productData = new ComApiData<GetProductsDataConnector>();

            var products = productData.Connector.GetProductBySearch(new ProductRequestParameters()
            {
                Search = keywords,
                LTPMerchantId = merchantId,
                QueryLimit = queryLimit,
                QueryOffset = offset
            });

            searchResults.ProductDetails = products.ToList();

            return PartialView("_SearchResults", searchResults);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

And there is a button on the form:

```
<a id="draftAddProduct" class="hollow button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add Product</a>
```

Since I am new to this side of development, I need a little help.  I need to wire up the button to take the value typed in the text call the SearchResults controller (located in a file called ProductsController.cs) and populate a modal dialog box with the results.  I have a partial razor page:

```
    @model Sauron.Models.Products.ProductSearchResults

@foreach (var product in Model.ProductDetails)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="imageColumn">
            @if (product.Image != null)
            {
                <div class="ajax-image-load">
                    <input type="hidden" id="BlockImageID" value="@product.Image.ImageId" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="BlockImageWidth" value="89" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="BlockImageHeight" value="89" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="BlockImageLoaderGif" value="/images/loader-circle-basic.gif" />
                </div>
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @product.SKU
            <input type="hidden" id="editID" name="editID" value="@product.ProductId" />
        </td>
        <td>@(product.Description != null ? product.Description.Name : product.ReceiptName)</td>
        @*<td>@(product.ColorId != null ? product.)</td> we might want to gather the color object as a property of this search class model*@
        <td>
            @{
                var textColor = "";
                if((product.InventorySummary ?? 0) <= 0){
                    textColor = "red-text";
                }
            }
            <span class="@textColor">@((product.InventorySummary ?? 0).ToString())</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (product.ProductType != null ? product.ProductType.Equals(ProductType.PACK) : false)
            {
                <span>@(product.PackQty != null ? string.Format("{0} {1}", product.PackQty.Value, product.ProductType.ToString()) : product.ProductType.ToString())</span>
            }
            else if (product.ProductType != null ? product.ProductType.Equals(ProductType.CASE) : false)
            {
                <span>@(product.PackQty != null ? string.Format("{0} {1}", product.PackQty.Value, product.ProductType.ToString()) : product.ProductType.ToString())</span>
            }
            else
            {
                <span>@(product.ProductType != null ? product.ProductType.ToString() : "")</span>
            }
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

that will display the results.  I need to display the results of the _SearchResults.cshtml page in a modal box.

I want to call the SearchResults method from the values entered in the text box to display the results.

Anyone's help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was calling the controller by the wrong name.  Once I got the right name, it started working.

Code:

```
 $('#draftAddProduct').click(function () {
    var keyWord = $('#draftProductModal').val();
    $('#draftProductModal').load("@Url.Action("SearchResults","Products")?keywords=chair");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer for this question here:
[Bootstrap Modal Dialog - Loading Content from MVC Partial View](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/826002/Bootstrap-Modal-Dialog-Loading-Content-from-MVC-Pa)